# How to ignore folder in site root while accessing a URL

Tags: htaccess

I have a folder in my site's public_html directory called `/connect`. The folder is causing the page `sitename.com/connect` to access a parent index page instead of the Wordpress page set up.

Deleting this folder solves the problem, but this folder keeps getting added daily by my autoSSL program. It was due to a `connect.sitename.com` subdomain being set up, but even after removing that from the DNS, it is still being added daily.

Is there anything that I can do to the htaccess file, or anything else to ignore that folder and use the Wordpress page I've set up?

There is no way that I can change the URL, the client has sent out print media with the URL on it.

Comment: You can move all files related to your Wordpress website to an other folder and edit the domain settings pointing to the new folder.

Comment: Just did that following [this guide](https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/), but it didn't solve the issue. Site is still reachable, but the /connect page is still being overwritten with the folder in the public_html directory

Comment: The new folder should not be nested in any way inside the connect folder. If you edit the domain settings in your hosting panel to the new folder you can‘t still have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordinarily, requests for physical directories (and files) are not routed to WordPress. You could make an exception for this one folder (or URL) and specifically rewrite requests for `/connect` to `index.php` (the WordPress front-controller).

Try the following *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` section:

```
# Override directory
RewriteRule ^connect index.php [L]
```